# Infopath: querying a data source via web services

Tags: infopath

I am getting this error after publishing the form. However, no error is given when I do a preview in the infopath. Please suggest.

> An error occurred querying a data source.  Click OK to resume filling
>   out the form. You may want to check your form data for errors.
>
> Hide error details  An error occurred while trying to connect to a Web
>   service.
>
> An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server.  Log
>   ID:5566
>
> Correlation ID:f887f622-8d9d-493f-a744-4a4b58f29806
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- An error occurred while trying to connect to a Web service.
>
> An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server.  Log
>   ID:5566
>
> Correlation ID:f887f622-8d9d-493f-a744-4a4b58f29806

Comment: This could be a number of issues, perhaps a failed authorization. Are you previewing on the same server as your are deploying? What is the log entry associated with that correlation ID?

Comment: I am using my local to design n publish. went to both wfe and i get the same error that i was getting when i used my local desktop internet explorer.

Comment: Can you detail the error that you are getting in the ULS logs?

Comment: @Everyone: Strangely the form started working. I came in this morning everything looks good. But I suspecting it will happen again so still need to fix the issue. Deepu: Which ULS logs (wfe1 or wfe2 or app/ca/index server)?

Comment: The problem appears again. hmm. Can anyone please suggest a fix? on a deadline here.

Comment: Okay, Added Host entry on the both WFE and problem went away for good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added Host entry on both WFE and problem went away for good. The WFE IP address and same portal site. For example,

On WFE1 I added

```
192.168.77.201    Portal.SP.com
```

On WFE2 I added

```
192.168.77.202    Portal.SP.com
```

Now, it's all good.

Comment: Hi Mr Todd, can you please let me know what WFE means?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. Struggled a lot and got an exact solution for this. http://techilatalk.com/get-spserviceapplication-not-working/ .

This solution gives database based approach to handle this issue.

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.
Thanks.